# MongoModel gem vs the schemaless database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, schema

I'm using the MongoModel gem in a Ruby on Rails project and it works fine. Works fine as long as you strictly follow the structure defined in your models, so basically using MongoDB as a database with schema. But one of the advantages of MongoDB, well, from a certain perspective, is that it is a schemaless database. And I would like to make use of it, add random fields to documents, just as you can in the mongo shell.

How to do that? Is there a way?

Update:

I'm trying to make it more clear why I am asking this, especially in reply to comments from zero.zero.seven and j03w. It's not because I'm lazy to figure out a structure, it's because I want to make use of this excellent feature, flexibility, of Mongo.

I've done a **similar thing** previously on MS SQL and .Net. The structure for a part of the database was defined in an XML file which defined the form and not a table. Values of the form were stored in a vertical structure, like, with the ID of the instance of the current item in question and the ID of the field on the form, all integers went to the "integers" table, strings to the "strings" table. This gave me **flexibility**: if somebody found out that they needed new pieces of information to get their job done, they just had to edit the XML and add new fields in it. They were displayed on the form and stored in the vertical DB structure. But of course it also had its drawbacks: a lot more records, less clear database, table structure not reflecting your information structure. Performance, maybe.

Now it is a piece of cake as long as you're playing with this in the Mongo console. But how can you do it in Rails? I'm looking for a solution where you can define structures somewhere else, not in a model. Some fields would be ubiquitous, of course, one of them could be the "subject". So if subjects says "travel", the application would ask you for "destination" and "departure date" and when it says "calendar entry", you would be prompted for "appointment date" and "participants". So there is a structure but that changes from instance to instance, from document to document.

Comment: then you should use random classes for each random document, as far as I got from this page : http://www.mongomodel.org/documents you define documents by classes, if you want random functionality, then you need random class generation, take a look at meta classes.

Comment: I think I understand you but this means that you're losing the flexibility of Mongo DB. I just don't want to believe that the answer is "migrate to MongoID". (Maybe, I don't know too much about MongoID)

Comment: If you want flexibility then you should generate documents dynamically, for MongoModel it means generate classes dynamically, 
I hope these help you:
http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/
http://yinkei.com/the-ruby-metaclass/

Comment: you may consider this From mongoengine documentation:

    MongoDB is schemaless, which means that no schema is enforced by the database — we may add and remove fields however we want and MongoDB won’t complain. This makes life a lot easier in many regards, especially when there is a change to the data model. However, defining schemata for our documents can help to iron out bugs involving incorrect types or missing fields, and also allow us to define utility methods on our documents in the same way that traditional ORMs do.

Comment: It schemaless like how JSON doesn't require formal schema declaration but it doesn't mean you don't need schema at all. The db engine may not care so much about what you are storing however, unless you just take user input and print it back later you will need schema. At least to a certain extend. You need a schema for MongoDB the same way you need a documentation for JSON REST API. Have a look at this awesome talk from Martin Fowler http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qI_g07C_Q5I

Read the question again my comment may be off-topic but I'll leave it  here nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far, I've updated the question to explain my topic further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to close this question so please consider it as a knowledge sharing one. The final solution was to switch from MongoModel to Mongoid about 5-6 weeks ago.

Mongomodel worked absolutely well, it is a perfect solution as long as you have a really database-like (not to say "legacy") approach to the information you want to manage in your application. But I couldn't figure out how to get rid of the structural constraints of the models.

Now Mongoid is different. In your `mongoid.yml` file you can set an option like:

```
allow_dynamic_fields: true
```

This gives you the freedom I needed with the `read_attribute` and `write_attribute` methods:

```
# Raise a NoMethodError if value isn't set.
person.gender
person.gender = "Male"

# Retrieve a dynamic field safely.
person[:gender]
person.read_attribute(:gender)

# Write a dynamic field safely.
person[:gender] = "Male"
person.write_attribute(:gender, "Male")
```

And voilá! You're developing MVC with strict models, yet you can add *any* field to the MongoDB document, not even mentioned in the model.

See more [in the mongoid documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#dynamic_fields).